# How to set default settings for "Find and replace"

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to save the settings in Google Sheets' `Find and replace` so that the options that are selected become the default search options? If so, how?

Example:
The `Find and replace` window below has `Match case` and `Match entire cell contents` selected. From here we can enter the contents to search for, but the options will only "stick" for this one-time search.

[image]

What I would like is for `Match case` and `Match entire cell contents` to be applied to all my searches that I may do through the default `Find` window shown here...

[image]

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no". That sounds like a bit of feedback that should be passed to Google to see if they'll implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time Google Sheets official documentation doesn't mention a way to default settings for Find and Replace. An alternative is to emulate the find and replace features by using [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start), and more specifically the array handling features of JavaScript.